# haskell, deriving Show in class and in all instances

Tags: haskell

That's signature of my class:

```
 class (Ord a) => Test a where
```

I would like to be able show element `a` from all instances of class `Test`.
So far I have used `deriving Show` mechanism only in connection to data type.

Could you help me ?

Comment: perhaps add `Show a` as a qualifier?

Comment: since `show a` will work, wrap it with what you want for `Test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require that to be part of the `Test` type class you need to also belong to `Show` with

```
  class (Ord a, Show a) => Test a where
```

and then you can write a function like

```
printTest :: Test a => a -> IO ()
printTest a = putStrLn (show a) -- equivalent to print a
```

because GHC will infer that if `Test a` holds then `Show a` must as well.

But it almost seems like this isn't what you're asking for, if you want to specify *a new `Show` instance* for every type which belongs to `Test` then sadly you're out of luck. You could imagine writing something like

```
 instance Test a => Show a where
   ...
```

but this isn't going to work properly, in particular it will "overlap" with all other instances in a most unpleasant way and trying to fix this is just going to leave you with 2 dozens tabs into the GHC extensions manual and an elevated blood pressure. Some libraries provide a function

```
 defaultShow :: Test a => a -> String
```

if they define a type class where you would like to do this which simplifies the processes of defining such a `Show` instance but it's no more concise than just using `deriving` truthfully.

Comment: Is it possinble to create instance of class such that this instance has deriving show ?

Comment: @HaskellFun An instance cannot have a deriving clause itself, the type you are making an instance for may or may not have a deriving clause for Show but it isn't possible to require this beyond simply requiring that the type implement `Show` somehow.